# PPTP VPN Ubuntu no web access

Tags: iptables, nat, pptp

I've set up a PPTPd server on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine with kernel 5.0x, am able to connect to it from a Win10 machine, ping the server **and ping 8.8.8.8**. So DNS works over VPN.
However, I'm not able to retrieve any web pages or connect to other ports.

I've done the modprobe things (nf_nat_pptp and nf_conntrack_pptp).

The server has a local address of 192.168.0.1 and the client receives 192.168.0.100, as per defaults. The iptables below show some other address ranges that were used for testing.

I'm pretty sure it's an iptables issue but I don't have experience tracing these kind of issues by just looking at the rules list.

```
# sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper = 1
```

---

```
# iptables -nvL -t nat --line-number
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 239K packets, 23M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     252K   25M PREROUTING_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2     252K   25M PREROUTING_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 50342 packets, 2729K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 62252 packets, 4500K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1    62476 4516K OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 21854 packets, 1580K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1    40409 2921K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2       70  4886 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3        5   325 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4    22005 1590K POSTROUTING_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
5    22005 1590K POSTROUTING_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
6        6   432 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
7        0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
8        0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING_ZONES (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 POST_public  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.0/24      [goto]
2    22005 1590K POST_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain POSTROUTING_direct (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POST_public (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1    22005 1590K POST_public_pre  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2    22005 1590K POST_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3    22005 1590K POST_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4    22005 1590K POST_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
5    22005 1590K POST_public_post  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain POST_public_allow (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POST_public_deny (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POST_public_log (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POST_public_post (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POST_public_pre (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain PREROUTING_ZONES (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1    11025  842K PRE_public  all  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
2     241K   24M PRE_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain PREROUTING_direct (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain PRE_public (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     252K   25M PRE_public_pre  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2     252K   25M PRE_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3     252K   25M PRE_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4     252K   25M PRE_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
5     252K   25M PRE_public_post  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain PRE_public_allow (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain PRE_public_deny (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain PRE_public_log (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain PRE_public_post (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain PRE_public_pre (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

---

```
# iptables -nvL --line-number
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     5673  557K ACCEPT     47   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2     5071  511K ACCEPT     47   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3       83  4400 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1723 state NEW
4     1532  141K ACCEPT     47   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
5        1    52 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1723 state NEW
6     1759  163K ACCEPT     47   --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
7     555K   94M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT
8    21994 1589K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
9     110K 6423K INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
10   72059 4171K INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
11    8933  364K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
12   11808 1026K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
13       0     0 ACCEPT     47   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
14       0     0 ACCEPT     47   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
15       0     0 ACCEPT     47   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     2072  108K TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU
2        0     0 TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      *       10.0.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU
3     3739  194K TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU
4        0     0 TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU
5        0     0 ACCEPT     47   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
6       80  5808 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT
7        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
8     8862  510K FORWARD_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
9     8862  510K FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
10    8819  507K FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
11       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
12    8819  507K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
13       0     0 TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x17/0x02 TCPMSS set 1356
14       0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  ppp+   eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
15       0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   ppp+    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
16       0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  ppp+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 603K packets, 125M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     8423  599K ACCEPT     47   --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2    43988 3795K ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3     627K  136M OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4        0     0 ACCEPT     47   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
5        0     0 ACCEPT     47   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     8862  510K FWDI_public  all  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
2        0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.0/24      [goto]
2     8819  507K FWDO_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     8862  510K FWDI_public_pre  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2     8862  510K FWDI_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3     8862  510K FWDI_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4     8862  510K FWDI_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
5     8862  510K FWDI_public_post  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
6       43  3348 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_post (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_pre (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     8819  507K FWDO_public_pre  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2     8819  507K FWDO_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3     8819  507K FWDO_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4     8819  507K FWDO_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
5     8819  507K FWDO_public_post  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_post (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_pre (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     1214  114K IN_public  all  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
2    70845 4058K IN_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1    37532 2252K REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587,143,993,110,995 match-set f2b-postfix-sasl src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
2        1    60 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22 match-set f2b-sshd src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain IN_public (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1    72059 4171K IN_public_pre  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2    72059 4171K IN_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3    72059 4171K IN_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4    72059 4171K IN_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
5    20855 1397K IN_public_post  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
6      114  6638 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     2000 84664 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
2       21   868 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
3       27  1460 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:993 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
4       12   496 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:465 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
5      676 36856 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
6    11957  717K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
7      186 10756 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:110 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
8     4329  238K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
9       25  1368 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:995 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
10      21  1088 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:143 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
11       3   120 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:20 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
12     114  5008 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:10000:10100 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
13      26  1376 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:20000 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
14      31  2022 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
15       7   288 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
16   31049 1629K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:1025:65535 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
17       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:2222 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
18     720 43028 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_public_post (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_public_pre (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely something wrong with iptables rules. I see a lot of overlapping. For example, take a close look at `POSTROUTING` chain. Rules #1, 2 and 3 are identical. Also, rules #6, 7 and 8 are identical.

Bear in mind that rules are processed from top to down. If you take another close look at `POSTROUTING_ZONES` chain. Rule #1 has no hit (0 pkts). It means traffic is being blocked by earlier rules. I suggest you do a rule cleanup, and re-add rules making sure that you do not duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, dns is working, I am able to ping an uncached hostname and it will resolve it and I can also ping any host. But I cannot transfer data from port 80 or 443 or any other port. So ICMP forwarding works, but not generic TCP/UDP.

Comment: Edit your question, remove the iptables output and replace with "iptables -nvL -t nat --line-number" and "iptables -nvL --line-number" output. This output will show the rules in sequence numbers, and we can all analyze and identify the possible errors

Comment: Thank you for the followup, I've edited the question.

Comment: Definitely something wrong with iptables rules. I see a lot overlapping. For example, take  a close look at POSTROUTING chain. Rules #1, 2 and 3 are identical. Also, rules #6, 7 and 8 are identical. Rules are processed from top to down. Take another look at POSTROUTING_ZONES chain. Rule #1 has no hit (0 pkts). It means traffic is being blocked by earlier rules. I suggest a rule cleanup.

Comment: I managed to fixed it by dropping the rules 11 and 12 in the FORWARD chain. Not sure what impact on security that has, hopefully not major. I cannot clear all the rules since I have no physical access to the system, other than re-installing it. I would suggest you add your last comment as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: Thank @brainwash for your kindness

Comment: Thank YOU! Wish you nice holidays